# how to get images in a row grow the same height, regardless of their initial height

Tags: css, flexbox, grid, multiple-columns

Images speak better than words. I have this:

[image]

which should become this:

[image]

But these pictures have **different sizes and aspect-ratio**, I want them to fill the row but grow to get the same height. I tried to play with the flex property but this only change the MAIN - inline - axis, because it's a row.
it would place all images in a row, with an equal height of 1px, then grow the items until they reached the max-height of the parent.

I tried to look for answers on this one but couldn't. I'm open to grid or whatever else you come up with.
thanks.

```
<ul class="center row aside">
<li><strong>this</strong> being the same people
<li>
    <ul class=center>
    <li><figure><a href=image1 https://website.org/Images/history/antiquity/mudpot.jpg target=_blank><img src=image1 srcset="SRCSET1" alt sizes="(max-width: 400px) 100vw, (max-width: 604px) 50vw, 35vw" width=661 height=1200></a></figure>
    <li><figure><a href=image2 target=_blank><img src=image2 srcset="SRCSET2" alt=diorite sizes="(max-width: 400px) 100vw, (max-width: 604px) 50vw, 35vw" width=640 height=826></a></figure></ul>
<li>Then <strong>this</strong> would be too
<li>
    <ul class=center>
    <li><figure><a href=https://website.org/Images/history/tajmahal.jpg target=_blank><img src=https://website.org/Images/history/tajmahal.jpg srcset="SRCSET" alt sizes="(max-width: 400px) 100vw, (max-width: 604px) 50vw, 35vw" width=5463 height=4216></a></figure>
    <li><figure><a href=https://website.org/Images/history/antiquity/mudhouse.jpg target=_blank><img src=https://website.org/Images/history/antiquity/mudhouse.jpg srcset="SRCSET" sizes="(max-width: 400px) 100vw, (max-width: 604px) 50vw, 35vw" width=194 height=260></a></figure></ul></ul>
```

```
/* SASS */
figure{
    margin:auto; max-width:50%;
    float:right; clear:right;
    a {display:flex;}
    img{z-index:1; margin:auto;
        width:100%;height:100%;}
}
.center {
    width:100%; display: grid;
    margin: auto; float:none;
    justify-items:center; text-align:center;
    text-wrap:balance; max-width:unset;
    &:is(ul){grid-auto-flow: column;
             figure{max-width:unset}}
    &:is(figure){grid-auto-flow: row}
}
.center .center {margin:0}
.center.row {grid-auto-flow: row}
```

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried because from your description I can’t see why it wouldn’t work just using img elements. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Corrected. With an example and the css (sass) used.